# Use value form drop down menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a menu such as this:

```
<select>
<option value="21">option a</option>
<option value="13">option b</option>
<option value="21">option c</option>
</select>
```

Depending on what option is being selected I need get the corresponding value to use elsewhere in links and images. (it also needs to pull from the default option before it is clicked)

```
<img src="mysite.com/images/[valuegoeshere].jpg">
<a href="mysite.com/pages/[valuegoeshere].jpg">
```

There are several unique versions of these drop downs on page.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `<select>` tags contains `<option>s` not the other way around

Comment: Looking at your tags, both PHP and jQuery are good.

Comment: also select has wrong markup .. option doest not include select.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd What would I echo in PHP?

Comment: @Ankur I tried a combination of PHP/Jquery and it was a mess. there has to be a simple way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following on [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
function update(val) {
  $("img").attr("src", "mysite.com/images/" + val + ".jpg");
  $("a").attr("href", "mysite.com/pages/" + val + ".jpg");
}

var defaultVal = $("select").change(function () {
  update(this.value); // update <img> and <a> with the newly selected value
}).val();

update(defaultVal); // update <img> and <a> with the default value
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVG2M/)**.

Comment: It's effecting every image and link on my page; not just "mysite.com/pages" ones. jQuery(document).ready(function() {

`function update(val) {
  jQuery("img").attr("src", "mysite.com/images/" + val + ".jpg");
  jQuery("a").attr("href", "mysite.com/pages/" + val + ".jpg");
}

var defaultVal = jQuery("select").change(function () {
  update(this.value); // update <img> and <a> with the newly selected value
}).val();

update(defaultVal); // update <img> and <a> with the default value
});`

Comment: @SamDanger: Simply change the selector from `img` and `a` to the `id`s that you want to modify.

Comment: Now it's not effecting anything.  `jQuery("imageposh").attr("src", "mysite.com/images/" + val + ".jpg");
  jQuery("lightboxposh").attr("href", "mysite.com/pages/" + val + ".jpg");
a href="mysite.com/pages/[valuegoeshere].jpg" id="lightboxposh">
<img src="mysite.com/images/[valuegoeshere].jpg"id="imageposh"></a>
}`

Comment: Is `imageposh` the `id` of the `img`? You need to use `jQuery("#imageposh")` instead, with the `#`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Joao. The only problem now is that it is the default is not working. When I use the select I get the correct url/image but it shows "/pages/mage.jpg".

Comment: I assigned an ID to (select) and now it's working . thanks big time joao!

Answer (score 2):

you can get the selected value by handling change event of select drop down like this

```
$('#yourselectid').change(function(){
currentSelectedValue=$(this).val();
alert(currentSelectedValue);
})
```

Working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yeZ3j/

UPDATED FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/yeZ3j/1/

**Updated Code:**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    currentSelectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('img').attr('src', 'mysite.com/images/' + currentSelectedValue + '.jpg');
    $('a').attr('href', 'mysite.com/images/' + currentSelectedValue + '.jpg');

    $('body').append('<br>currentSource of img is :' + $('img').attr('src') + ' and anchor is: ' + $('a').attr('href'))
});
$(function() {
    $('select').trigger('change')
})​
```

Comment: Thanks @ashirvad. Now the other points in my question; how could call it out to use in an src/href and how can use this multiple times uniquely on one page?

Comment: yes, by default the top of this list shows as selected and that needs give it's value without clicking.

Comment: It's effecting every img /href on the entire page

Comment: (document).ready(function()  guarantees that your DOM is ready for modification. So it is needed for first trigger ..

Answer (score 0):

If the form is being submitted as a GET request, then this would be easy. Also remember to give a `name` attribute to the select.  If you want to do it server-side and the `name` attribute is "my_name", then PHP to change the value of a link would look like this:

```
$option = $_GET["my_name"];
$link_text = "<a href='mysite.com/pages/" . $option . ".jpg'>link</a>";
$img_text = "<img src='mysite.com/images/" . $option . ".jpg' />";
echo $img_text . "\n" . $link_text;
```